# Sorting an numpy array in numba no-python mode

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sorting, numba

[Numba documentation](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/reference/numpysupported.html) suggests the following code should compile

```
@njit()
def accuracy(x,y,z):
    x.argsort(axis=1)
    # compare accuracy, this code works without the above line  
    accuracy_y = int(((np.equal(y, x).mean())*100)%100)
    accuracy_z = int(((np.equal(z, x).mean())*100)%100)
    return accuracy_y,accuracy_z
```

It fails on `x.argsort()`, I have also tried the following with and without axis arguments

```
np.argsort(x)
np.sort(x)
x.sort()
```

However I get the following failed to compile error (or similar):

```
numba.core.errors.TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
No implementation of function Function(<function sort at 0x000001B3B2CD2EE0>) found for signature:
 
 >>> sort(array(int64, 2d, C))
 
There are 2 candidate implementations:
  - Of which 2 did not match due to:
  Overload of function 'sort': File: numba\core\typing\npydecl.py: Line 665.
    With argument(s): '(array(int64, 2d, C))':
   No match.

During: resolving callee type: Function(<function sort at 0x000001B3B2CD2EE0>)



File "accuracy.py", line 148:
def accuracy(x,lm,sfn):
    <source elided>
    # accuracy
    np.sort(x)
    ^
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: You seem to be missing the part that declares and fills z, y and z.

Comment: I pass arrays into this in the function however in it's current form it doesn't matter what you try to pass it won't compile due to the `np.sort(x)` line being passed into numba.

Comment: It seems you are passing a 2d array but numba only supports 1d

Comment: What you pass to it defines what is compiled. That is the whole point of Numba. I would guess the two dimensional arrays you haven’t shown are the problem. The compiler probably only has a lowering for 1D inputs

Comment: See https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/4636

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also consider using `guvectorize` if it fits your use case. That gives the benefit of being able to specify the axis to sort over. Sorting over more than 1 dimension can be done by repeated calls over a different axis.

```
@guvectorize("(n)->(n)")
def sort_array(x, out):
    out[:] = np.sort(x)
```

Using a slightly different example array that also has columns unordered.

```
arr = np.array([
    [6,5,4],
    [3,2,1],
    [9,8,7]],
)

sort_array(arr, out, axis=0)
sort_array(out, out, axis=1)
```

Shows:

```
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])
```

Making a simple wrapper would allow sorting of an arbitrary number of dimensions at once. I don't think Numba's overload supports `guvectorize`, otherwise you could even use it to make `np.sort` work inside your jitted functions without having to change anything.

https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/extending/overloading-guide.html

Testing the output compared to Numpy:

```
for _ in range(20):
    
    arr = np.random.randint(0, 99, (9,9))

    # numba sorting
    out_nb = np.empty_like(arr)
    sort_array(arr, out_nb, axis=0)
    sort_array(out_nb, out_nb, axis=1)

    # numpy sorting
    out_np = np.sort(arr, axis=0)
    out_np = np.sort(out_np, axis=1)

    np.testing.assert_array_equal(out_nb, out_np)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the comments!
The following function sorts a 2d array!

```
from numba import njit
import numpy  as np

@njit()
def sort_2d_array(x):
    n,m=np.shape(x)
    for row in range(n):
        x[row]=np.sort(x[row])
    return x

arr=np.array([[3,2,1],[6,5,4],[9,8,7]])
y=sort_2d_array(arr)
print(y)
```

Comment: Note: there's probably and easy way to use @vectorize on this function